# CSS Background Images not loading in chrome

Tags: html, css

Here is my css

```
.nav_arrow {
    position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 15;
    background-image: url(../img/arrow-navpage.png) !important;
    width: 34px; height: 136px;
    margin-top: -68px;  }

    .nav_arrow.next         { right: -34px; background-position: 0 0; }
    .nav_arrow.next:hover   { background-position: 0 -186px; }

    .nav_arrow.prev         { left: -34px; background-position: 0 -372px; display: none; }
    .nav_arrow.prev:hover   { background-position: 0 -558px; }
```

Image is for next / previous button background

But its not loading in. can any one help me

Comment: Have you made sure your image path is correct?

Comment: Add this into fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Use only `background: url(../img/arrow-navpage.png) !important;`

Comment: @Igle what's wrong with `background-image`?

Comment: Also, you are using `nav_arrow.prev` so god knows how you can even display that in other browsers too

Answer (score 1):

Use **Elements inspector** (`press F12`) to see if the images are being loaded.

- In **Elements Tab** you can see if your CSS rule is correct, or by right
  clicking over the element itself
- Under **Resources Tab** you can see if the Image Path is correct and if
  the image are being loaded.

If those chechs are correct, probably you have a visualization problem with your CSS rule, probably position related.

Try it and tell us the result.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see the problem without a fiddle. But first check if the sprites image is loaded, then check `background-position` for every piece of the image. Also check if the `.nav-arrow` container has `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
 .nav_arrow.next         { right: -34px; background-position: 0px 0px; }
    .nav_arrow.next:hover   { background-position: -186px 0px; }
    .nav_arrow.prev         { left: -34px; background-position: -372px 0px; display: none; }
    .nav_arrow.prev:hover   { background-position: -558px 0px; }
```

I don't know why you use **left:-34px right:-34px;** if this answer not help you show us your code